# How can I indicate layer when drawing a polygon in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: polygon, google-earth-engine, layers, geometry, drawing

These lines of code help us draw polygons:

```
drawingTools.setShape('polygon');
drawingTools.draw();
```

But if I have two geometry layers, how can I specify to which the drawn geometry is to be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using this code:

```
var drawingTools = Map.drawingTools();
// Initialize empty geomtry layers as placeholder and fill them with drawn shapes
while (drawingTools.layers().length() === 0) {
  var dummyLayer1 = ui.Map.GeometryLayer({geometries: null, name: 'geometries1', color: 'grey'});
  var dummyLayer2 = ui.Map.GeometryLayer({geometries: null, name: 'geometries2', color: 'green'});
  drawingTools.layers().add(dummyLayer1 );
  drawingTools.layers().add(dummyLayer2 );
} 
function add_mouse_drawn_geometry_to_dummyLayer() {
  var dummyLayer1 = drawingTools.layers().get(0);
  var nbGeometries = dummyLayer1.geometries().length();
  var geometry = dummyLayer1.geometries().get(nbGeometries-1);
  
  var dummyLayer2 = drawingTools.layers().get(1);
  // Add the last drawn geometry to the selected layer.
  dummyLayer2.geometries().add(geometry);
}
```

Having 2 layers is in case we want to save only one type of shapes (e.g. only polygons)

Answer (score 0):

Method in **ui.Map.DrawingTools** for drawing objects is 'addLayer'; as it can be corroborated in following [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3e81500c68ab530eb90685c6174d478d).

```
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[51.50311161691894, 25.26703875176188],
          [51.50427033121338, 25.26502063795976],
          [51.50637318308105, 25.266146128641104],]], null, false);

var line = ee.Geometry.LineString(
        [[51.50068689996948, 25.265718411626974],
         [51.50210310632934, 25.26711556287879],
         [51.503841177770994, 25.267435741109228],
         [51.50550414736023, 25.267348419857395],
         [51.50741388017883, 25.266649847581526],
         [51.507789389440916, 25.264825778797746],
         [51.50964547807922, 25.26627145258692]]);

Map.centerObject(polygon);

var drawingTools = Map.drawingTools();

print(drawingTools);

drawingTools.addLayer([polygon], 'polygon', 'blue', true, true);

drawingTools.addLayer([line], 'line', 'red', true, true);
```